# exception 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception' with message 'Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Anyone know what this error means? after googling I found a bunch of sites that appear to have the same error? thanks

```
exception 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception' with message 'Action "index" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()' in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/pintsy/lib/Zend/Controller/Action.php:485
    Stack trace:
    #0 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/pintsy/lib/Zend/Controller/Action.php(515): Zend_Controller_Action->__call('indexAction', Array)
    #1 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/pintsy/lib/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
    #2 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/pintsy/lib/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
    #3 /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/pintsy/html/index.php(114): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
    #4 {main}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means there's no `indexAction` method in your controller class.

Your controller was instantiated and, based on the URL, Magento determined the action was "index".  This is the default action.  For example, if you have a URL like this

```
http://example.com/products/
```

is usually (Zend is used differently all over the place) the same as a URL like this

```
http://example.com/products/index
```

That is, they would both instantiate a `ProductController` and with an action of index.

```
public function indexAction(){...}
```

So, your controller is missing a method named indexAction.  What happens next is, the request is sent to PHP magic `__call` method.  If this method exists on a class, calls to non-existent methods go there.  The Zend Exception is telling you that, in addition to there being no method for `indexAction`, there was nothing in `__call` about `indexAction` either.

Answer (score 2):

If you got the same error in apache log means, it might be because of invalid path for the css or javascript or image files